# MS Teams Bot - remove all @mentions from text message

Tags: python, chatbot, microsoft-teams

I'm writing an interactive chat bot with MS Teams Bot Framework and I'm trying to remove all mentions from the chat message. i.e.
message I'm writing to the bot (inside Team channel with @general mention to push notification):

**"@general @bot hello world"**  my code expects only the text message without ANY mentions -> **"hello world".**

My code:

```
async def on_message_activity(self, turn_context: TurnContext):
        user = turn_context.activity.from_property.name
        turn_context.remove_recipient_mention(turn_context.activity)        
        user_input = turn_context.activity.text.strip()
```

I expect "turn_context.[remove_recipient_mention](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/botbuilder-core/botbuilder.core.turn_context.turncontext?view=botbuilder-py-latest#remove-recipient-mention-activity--botbuilder-schema--models-py3-activity-----str)(turn_context.activity)" to handle it and remove the recipients from the text message.

It works if I have only the @bot mention but doesn't work when I have multiple mentions in the message.

How can I get rid of all of the mentions from the chat message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can look at the method one above, on the link you sent, which is "remove_mention_text". This requires an ID for each mention, but if you look at the code ([here](https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-python/blob/fcfd6a25c23c75fa524b373232b1a174cec41e98/libraries/botbuilder-core/botbuilder/core/turn_context.py#L380)), it basically accesses `TurnContext.get_mentions(activity)`, so you could actually create your own method, like `remove_all_mentions`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of writing custom remove_all_mentions call `TurnContext.get_mentions(activity)` and for each mention call `TurnContext.remove_mention_text(turn_context.activity,mention_id)`

```
    async def on_message_activity(self, turn_context: TurnContext):
        user = turn_context.activity.from_property.name
        mentions = turn_context.get_mentions(turn_context.activity)
        if mentions:
            for mention in mentions:
                mention_id = mention.additional_properties["mentioned"]["id"]
                turn_context.remove_mention_text(turn_context.activity,mention_id)
```